# Get contents from each page in Crystal Report viewer and export it to a pdf

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I need to get the content inside each page of a crystal report viewer and export it to a pdf file so that each page becomes a separate pdf and need to zip them.
Now i'm using DotNetZip dll for this.That's fine.

The issue is that i need to get contents of each page.Please Help..Below is few lines of code

```
Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Reports.zip");
int i = 1;
int PageCount = report.FormatEngine.GetLastPageNumber(new 
                                    CrystalDecisions.Shared.ReportPageRequestContext());
if(PageCount >= 1){
     using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
     {
        for (i = 1; i <= PageCount; i++){
             var re = report.ExportToStream(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
             string Name = "Page" + i + ".pdf";
             zip.AddEntry(Name, re);
             
        }
        zip.Save(Response.OutputStream);
     }
}
```

Comment: You likely need to set PDF format options - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms226492(v=vs.90)

Comment: Thanks..Now i got each pages..But now i can't convert those pdf into a zip.I searched on internet but no solutions found.How can I do that ?

Comment: Honestly I have no idea about that :( Most likely zip component has some methods to add stream or files - you have to read documentation, not search on internet ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the answer!!..It may help someone in future.

```
Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Reports.zip");
int PageCount = report.FormatEngine.GetLastPageNumber(new 
                                      CrystalDecisions.Shared.ReportPageRequestContext());
if (PageCount >= 1)
{
    using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
        {
           for (int i = 1; i <= PageCount; i++)
               {
                   PdfRtfWordFormatOptions pdfRtfWordOpts = ExportOptions.CreatePdfRtfWordFormatOptions();
                   DiskFileDestinationOptions destinationOpts = ExportOptions.CreateDiskFileDestinationOptions();
                   ExportRequestContext req = new ExportRequestContext();
                   pdfRtfWordOpts.FirstPageNumber = i;
                   pdfRtfWordOpts.LastPageNumber = i;
                   pdfRtfWordOpts.UsePageRange = true;
                   ExportOptions CrExportOptions = report.ExportOptions;
                   {
                       CrExportOptions.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;
                       CrExportOptions.FormatOptions = pdfRtfWordOpts;
                       req.ExportInfo = CrExportOptions;
                   }
                   Stream s = report.FormatEngine.ExportToStream(req);
                   string Name = "Page" + i + ".pdf";
                   zip.AddEntry(Name, s);
               }
               zip.Save(Response.OutputStream);
        }
}
```